# How to run a job from a Jenkins Pipeline on the same executor (declarative syntax)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I want to use the Jenkins "PRQA" plugin, which seems not to have the option to use it from a pipeline. The plugin would run static code analysis and publish the results.
In my case, it requires some preparations that are already done in a pipelinejob. Because of that, I want to include the job into that pipeline, but on the same executor with the data prepared by the pipeline as some kind of inlined job-step.

I have tried to create a job for the PRQA-Plugin-Step and execute this with the build step from the pipeline. But this tries to start the job on a new executor (and stalls because I have only one executor).

```
pipeline {
   agent any
   stages {
      stage('Build') {
         steps {
            echo 'Prepare'
         }
      }
      stage('SCA') {
         steps {
           //Run this without using a new executor with the Environment that exists now
           build 'PRQA_Job'
         }
      }
   }
}
```

What is the correct way to run the job on the same executor with the current working directory.

Answer (score 1):

With specified `build 'PRQA_Job'` it's not possible to run second job on the same executor (1 job = 1 executor), since main job just waiting for a triggered job to be finished. But you can run another job on the same agent with more than 1 executor to reach workspace from main job.

For a test porpose specify agent name in both jobs: `agent 'agent_name_here'`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use plugin functionality for a plugin, which has no native pipeline support, you could try using  "step: General Build step" feature for Jenkins Pipelines. You can use the Pipeline Syntax wizzard linked in the Job configuration windows to generate the needed Pipeline description.

If the plugin does not show up in the "step: General Build step" part of Jenkins you can use a separate Job. To copy all the needed files/Data into this second Job you will require to use Archive Artifact/Copy Artifact functionality of Jenkins to save files from your Pipeline build.

For more information on  how to sue Archive Artifact/Copy Artifact see https://plugins.jenkins.io/copyartifact/ and
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/tests-and-artifacts/

Comment: Unfortunately the plugin does not show up in the Pipeline Syntax wizzard / step: General Build Step. Maybe because the plugin functionality is an Post-Build-Feature.
The Archive/Copy Artifact solution would probably work, but then an other executor is required, or the result is not shown in the Pipeline job